# Custom validator is not calling for each key press in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, custom-validators

I wrote a custom validator for Reactive forms in Angular 2.But my function is validating only first key press in the text field. Here my custom function supposed to validate each key press. Could any one please correct me.

This is the way I am calling custom function in my class.

```
  'customerNumberOwner': new FormControl('', [CustomValidators.CustomerNumberCustomValidation(6,8)]),
```

Here is my custom function.

```js
//Custom validator for Customer number owner
  static CustomerNumberCustomValidation(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      var reg=/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/;
        if(c && (c.value !== '')){
          const str=c.value;
         
              if (str.match(reg) || str.length<min ||str.length>max ){
                console.log('Invalid')
              return { 
                  'CustomerNumberCustomValidation' : true
                   };
              }
        
          }
      
      
      return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: How do you know that? Did you console.log() it? If yes, at which line in your code?

Comment: Debug using chrome debugger tool in. You'll sure get something.

Comment: @Lynx Here their is no problem with function, it was not called every key press.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxk3o7)

HTML:

```
<h1>
    Try Reactive Form Validation with custom validation
</h1>

<form [formGroup]="basicForm">
    <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter Name For Validation" />
    <p *ngIf="basicForm.get('name').hasError('required') && basicForm.get('name').touched">Required</p>
    <p *ngIf="basicForm.get('name').hasError('minlength')">Min Length 10</p>
    <p *ngIf="basicForm.get('name').hasError('maxlength')">Max Length 10</p>
    <p *ngIf="basicForm.get('name').hasError('CustomerNumberCustomValidation')">Pattern Invalid /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/</p>
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidatorService } from './custom-validator.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  basicForm: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  createForm() {
    this.basicForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.control(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), CustomValidatorService.CustomerNumberCustomValidation])
    })
  }
}
```

custom-validator.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class CustomValidatorService {

  constructor() { }

  static CustomerNumberCustomValidation(control: FormControl) {
    var reg = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/;
    if (control.value) {
      const matches = control.value.match(reg);
      return matches ? null : { 'CustomerNumberCustomValidation': true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```